# Creating combinations of two vectors

Tags: r

Suppose the following situation. There are two tables, each one of them with data of different quality. Both of them have the same variables A, B and C. Variables in the first table are called A1, B1 and C2, while those in the second table are called A2, B2, and C2.

The first table can be updated with the second table. There are six possible combinations:

A1, B1, C2

A1, B2, C1

A2, B1, C1

A1, B2, C2

A2, B1, C2

A2, B2, C1

The question is how to get that in R. What I'm using is what follows:

```
require(utils)
require(stringr)

vars <- c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2")

combine <- function(data, n){
  com1 = combn(data, n)# make all combinations
  com2 = c(str_sub(com1, end=-2L))# remove the number in the end of the name
  com3 = matrix(com2, nrow = dim(com1)[1], ncol = dim(com1)[2])# vector to matrix
  com3 = split(com3, rep(1:ncol(com3), each = nrow(com3)))# matrix to list
  com3 = lapply(com3, duplicated)# find list elements with duplicated names
  com3 = lapply(com3, function(X){X[which(!any(X == TRUE))]})# identify duplicated names
  pos = which(as.numeric(com3) == 0)# get position of duplicates
  com3 = com1[,pos]# return elements from the original list
  com3 = split(com3, rep(1:ncol(com3), each = nrow(com3)))# matrix to list
  com3 = lapply(com3, sort)# sort by alphabetical order
  com3 = as.data.frame(com3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)# matrix to data frame
  res = list(positions = pos, combinations = com3)# return position and combinations
  return(res)
}
combine(vars, 3)

$positions
[1]  1  4  6 10 11 15 17 20

$combinations
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A2 A2 A2 A2
2 B1 B1 B2 B2 B1 B1 B2 B2
3 C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2
```

I'd like to know if anyone knows a more straightforward solution than creating all possible combinations and afterwards cleaning up the result as my function does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over thinking the problem. Just use `expand.grid`:

```
> expand.grid(c('A1','A2'),c('B1','B2'),c('C1','C2'))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1   A1   B1   C1
2   A2   B1   C1
3   A1   B2   C1
4   A2   B2   C1
5   A1   B1   C2
6   A2   B1   C2
7   A1   B2   C2
8   A2   B2   C2
```

Comment: Nice.  I fooled around with `expand.grid` for 45min trying to get this.  Cheers!

Comment: This is one possibility. But how to return characters as characters? Note that `expand.grid` returns factors.

Comment: @Alessandro Set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` inside the `expand.grid` call.